# What's wrong with my SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for such a generic question, but I'm really struggling to find out why I'm getting the error `Unknown column 'tbl_downloads.itemid' in 'on clause'`. There is absolutely a column called itemid in the tbl_downloads table.

```
SELECT tbl_downloads.itemid,COUNT(tbl_downloads.itemid*temp1.score) AS score2
FROM tbl_downloads,temp1
LEFT JOIN temp2 ON tbl_downloads.itemid=temp2.itemid
WHERE temp2.itemid IS NULL
AND tbl_downloads.memberid=temp1.memberid
GROUP BY tbl_downloads.itemid
ORDER BY score2 DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's better to be consistent in your use of implicit and explicit join syntax - this would be an improvement:

```
SELECT tbl_downloads.itemid, COUNT(tbl_downloads.itemid*temp1.score) AS score2
FROM tbl_downloads
JOIN temp1 ON tbl_downloads.memberid=temp1.memberid
LEFT JOIN temp2 ON tbl_downloads.itemid=temp2.itemid
WHERE temp2.itemid IS NULL
GROUP BY tbl_downloads.itemid
ORDER BY score2 DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to go, `FROM tbl1, tbl2, tbl3` is not a good practice.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm really struggling to find out why I'm getting the error `Unknown column 'tbl_downloads.itemid' in 'on clause'`

The `LEFT JOIN` applies to `temp1` and `temp2`. The problem will become clearer if you format the query as follows:

```
SELECT ...
FROM tbl_downloads,
(temp1 LEFT JOIN temp2 ON tbl_downloads.itemid=temp2.itemid)
...
```

Thus `tbl_downloads` is not in scope in the `ON` clause.

Comment: You should not mix implicit joins (using `,`) and explicit joins (using the `join` keyword)